# SSAS 2005 query error 'The operation has been cancelled'

Tags: ssas

Context: SSAS 2005. I run a MDX query in SSMS, the query will throw error 'The operation has been cancelled.' whenever the execution time reaches 50 seconds (or 49 seconds, 48 seconds some times). I have already set ServerTimeOut to 0 and restarted the SSAS server. Any idea? I googled a bit and I am sure there is no processing when the query is running. In SQL Profiler I can only see an error event with the same information as in the SSMS. The log file has nothing recorded regarding this.  But I do see the memory going up all the way until the query fails. Any idea?

Update

Ok it turns out I didn't set a relationship between a dimension and a measure group. I am not 100% clear about the issue but not it's sure it's not related to server properties nor processing while executing the query.

Comment: It seems that Microsoft also realized that the error message is a bit unspecific, and improved it with an update for SSAS 2008: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2216456/en-us. This cannot be applied to your 2005 server, but maybe the different messages listed in this article can give you a hint what may have happened.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I later found I can also get the error message when the query is less efficient. E.g. when cross join several sets without using nonempty function against a measure (I used non empty key word at first).